# iPhone: Start or Download App if not exists from Safari

Tags: iphone

I know its possible to open an app from mobile safari using custom URL Handlers.

Is it possible to open the App Store from Safari on the iPhone and automatically install the app?

Or might it even be possible to open the app if it exists on the users device and to download it if it doesn't?

Best,
heinrich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't automatically install the app, but you can go to an App Store URL via `UIApplication`'s `openURL:` method.

To open another app from within yours, see this question: [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone).  (I don't know how you'd find out if the other app is installed.  Maybe just try to open it, and if that fails, open the App Store URL?)

Comment: Automatically downloading an application from the App Store would seem to be a potential security problem, so I doubt Apple would ever make that possible.