# Is it possible to kick off an app from another iphone app?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to start up the App Store from within my iphone app. Is this possible - and how?

Thanks.

Comment: By "kick off" you mean launch or start?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this URL prefix will launch it.

```
 itms-apps://
```

Other apps also have URLs you can use to launch them. You can register your own as well.

```
http://www.mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone) question on stackoverflow, it is not possible.

It may still be possible to communicate with a different app through a URL scheme, if that's what you want to do.  Read about that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone/419296#419296).