# merging 2 iphone applications

Tags: ios, iphone

I have 2 iphone app one for just info is now used and uploaded to appstore 
 and the other one that i m coding ll be finished by the end of march. and i want to merge these two app. For example  when  i bush a button in my new iphone app i want to open the old one that is already at the appstore .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

One way I know of doing it is using custom URL schemes, i.e. making the app which you want launched by the other app listen to a URL scheme, which you set inside the Info.plist file and then in your app delegate of the target app you need to implement: 
`-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;` which is your entry point when the other app opens it.

Look here for more info:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html