# iOS - open another application that exists on the phone?

Tags: iphone, ios, external-application

- Is it possible to open another application that exists on the phone from my app?
- Is it possible to check for availablility of an external application?

The other application is also my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the iOS URL handling features-- for example UIApplication canOpenURL:.