# Open application with bundle identifier

Tags: iphone, cfbundleidentifier

Is it possible to open a application from our application with `bundle identifier`. Suppose I have two apps installed on device one with `com.test.app1` and `com.test.app2`. Can I open app1 from my app2.

I know about openUrl method. for that I have to register url scheme in info.plist. and then i can use following method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:[NSURL urlWithString:@"myApp1://"]];
```

But what if I didn't register url scheme or don't know the registered url.

Any idea..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Are you sure that this is not possible..? Because we can check if application is installed in device or not with bundle identifier. so I was wondering that there may be some method for open it.

Comment: I don't think an Apple approved way exists.

Answer (score 15):

You can use private API to do that

```
Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
NSObject * workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:@selector(defaultWorkspace)];
BOOL isopen = [workspace performSelector:@selector(openApplicationWithBundleID:) withObject:@"com.apple.mobilesafari"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works on iOS 11, and don't need to know URL scheme.

Comment: Except you should never use private APIs.

Comment: @ekscrypto But I think it's the only way to match the requirements. And by the way, we successfully uploaded app with this code to AppStore.

Comment: being able to snoop a private api usage by the app review team should not be seen as an authorization to use a private api.

Comment: I get the error

```Implicitly declaring library function 'objc_getClass' with type 'id (const char *)'```

on the first line

Comment: @LuísCunha `#import <objc/runtime.h>` on the top of the file

Comment: Thanks so much bro, I was wondering how other apps (on the appstore btw) were doing this and I tried countless solutions that didn't work, until this one.

Answer (score 12):

The Swift version of @EvanJIANG answer.

```
guard let obj = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace") as? NSObject else { return false }
let workspace = obj.perform(Selector(("defaultWorkspace")))?.takeUnretainedValue() as? NSObject
let open = workspace?.perform(Selector(("openApplicationWithBundleID:")), with: "com.apple.mobilesafari") != nil
return open
```

Comment: this worked for me, will my app gonna pass Apple review with this?

Comment: I am using this just to open different apps using their bundle id's

Comment: this works. Just tested today. running latest version of Xcode and on device I have running iOS 15.3.1 (19D52)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `openUrl` call, but in order to succeed you must add some values to your project's `xy-Info.plist` file.

[image]

Once you've done that you can then call:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:[NSURL urlWithString:@"xingipad://"]];`

Answer (score 2):

Answer: You can't open app directly only with Bundle identifier.

Solution: You can implement deep linking (and take your bundle id as your deep linking id)concept to do this: [Deep-linking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45188793/3024579)

Comment: The question already included deep linking, asker was trying to find a way around that

Comment: All steps of deep linking are given in the above answer.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible using URL Schemes .

Comment: I know that this is possible with URL Scheme but I want to know that is this possible using bundle identifier?? If I don't have url scheme register than is this possible to open an app.