# Launch iPhone Application with Identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I'm trying to Launch an application within my App.
For example: If I press a Button in my testApp1, it should Open up testApp2.
Is there any Way to do this with the App Identifier??

I heard something about a undocumented method called `launchApplicationWithIdentifier: suspend:` but that doesn't work for me, or i'm using it wrong.
I tried this:
`[UIApplication launchApplicationWithIdentifier:@"com.test.testApp2" suspend:NO]`
But it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure **com.test.testApp2** corresponds to the value in the CFBundleIdentifier key of the application’s Info.plist file ??

Comment: Yes, i am, but it's still Not working. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:]`. You'll need set a custom URL scheme in your second app for that. Check [this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) or simply do a search with "iphone custom URL schemes". There's a lot of good tutorials.

Comment: I Alredy thought about that, but what should i do If I want to Launch an App which has no Custom URL scheme, for example a Alredy installed app??

Comment: If it's an app that you didn't developed, you'll have to seek it's URL scheme, for example, to launch twitter, the URL would look like: twitter:// here's a list of [third-party schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Third_Party_Applications)

Comment: But still you can't Open every app you want, cause i don't think EVERY App has his own URL scheme. For example, what should i do If i want to Open the "iPod" app on my iPhone??

Comment: That's the point, you can't launch every app on iOS. All you can do is check for each app if it can be opened using a URL scheme.

Comment: So there's absolutly no Chance to Open a with it's Identifier??  Cause i searched Google and found sind posts in some Forums were People say you can Launch ANY App with it's Identifier by using `[UIApplication launchapplicationwithidentifier: suspend: ]`

Comment: I didn't find any DOCUMENTED way to do that, and checking UIApplication reference i can't find that method, maybe it's part of a  iOS private API or a OS X method

Comment: I don't know excatctly but i think it's a undocumented method.  If it IS Part of iOS private API, is there any posibilty how to still use that method??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i guess launchApplication is used for mac app thats why its showing warning. i will suggest you to create a custom URL and add it to plist file and then later you may launch your app using that url.

Comment: Yeah, i can do that If the app that i want to Launch is One of my own, but what should i do If the app has no Custom URL scheme (a Alredy installed App.)??