# How to integrate one iphone app into another app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

we have developed a iPad app which is live on the appstore now. My clients are very interested in the app and want to use its features in their iPad app. They would want us to play our app through their app and servers. To be precise, they want us to integrate our app into  their app. But, we are not willing to share our source codes with each other. Is there any way in which this process can be done with out the actually sharing the source code?

Comment: will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone) help you?

Comment: You can build a static library. That way they could use your app's features without having your source code.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez: thanks emilio. Can you throw some more light on this static libraries concept. Any links on this topic would of great help.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: thanks krish. That link provides mus info on how to launch onw app from another. But, i need to know how to integrate one app into other

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can integrate one app into another one. But Apple provide a way to switch between app by using URL.

You can use this to launch an app:

- `(BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url` from UIApplication

The other app need to register an url in his info.plist and implements :

- `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` 
  With this, you can implement a easy way to switch between 2 apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you need use URL Schemes:

Essentially, one app registers the fact that it handles a particular URL prefix, and then to launch that app, you have to navigate to that URL.

You can pass parameters through this URL too.

If you meant e-mail application, you can pass link according to mailto: scheme. The simplest example is @"**mailto:someone@example.com**".

thanks :)