# api for showing native calculator in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I have to create app which has requirement to integrate calculator. I want to know that is there any api which will show a calculator. or i have to create the calculator?

I searched on google but it was showing me calculator application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NO, You have create the calculator and integrate it with application

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any particular API for interacting with the built-in calculator.

You are also unable to launch other applications from within your application, unless you are using [URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf) (here is a [long list of supported schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)), so you will need to create your own calculator.

Here is a similar question: [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)