# What is the scheme for calculator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to open the app "Calculator" but I don't know the Scheme

```
- (IBAction)btnColetorClick:(id)sender
{
    NSString *customURL = @"calculator://";

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"URL error"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No custom URL defined for %@", customURL]
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: you can find the list of url schemes in herE:http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: I didn't find calculator's scheme

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no scheme for the native calculator.

**Related:**

> [api for showing native calculator in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005748/api-for-showing-native-calculator-in-ios-app)

---

> [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `"calc://"`

it works on iOS13