# Calling another program

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, process

I'm working on monotouch framework, I'm writing an application for iPhone device, I want to call another program running on the iPhone from my own code...

Anyone can help me with this, usually in C# we just create a process for that exe file.

Is there anyway to do that with monotouch?????

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course use URL Schemes, but those suck. I have a blog post on super-duper-easy-peasy local cross-application communication using background tasks in iOS.

It's basically the same way that PhoneGap and Appcelerator Titanium work to communicate back to native platform specific APIs:

Code: https://github.com/anujb/MultitaskingHttp

Blog Post: http://blog.devnos.com/remember-when-apps-didnt-talk-to-each-other

Comment: Blog post link isn't working; Kindly post the the core of your post here;

Answer (score 1):

In Objective C code you can go with URL Schemes, using that you can launch another application from your application.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this can only be done of a URL scheme catches it. The long answer has, well---[already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone) :)