# How to open other application from our application in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create one application in my iphone so i want to do if i open my application the i am give one button if .I click that button then.I want to open other 10 application which is already in my iphone that application i have to open in my application which i create

can we use this as par my required

```
NSString *documentdir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]; 
NSString *tileDirectory = [documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xxxx/Tiles"]; 
NSLog(@"Tile Directory: %@", tileDirectory
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

Comment: if u not understand question then why people vote down .please those not understand question please i not need ur help .if u want to realy help it out any one then please give comment for more information other not say any thing or dont give vote down all some people are such a stupid

Answer (score 2):

Try this [link](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes). It will show you almost all the apps that you can open from your app using the URL Schemes and as the @trojanfoe has said, it is a duplicate.