# invoking the iOS application programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

I have designed sample applications and installed in the iPhone.

First application has a button in it, and i would like to get invoked the second application when the button is pressed. I am surfing to see the feasibility of it, but not sure if i have missed it.

Could someone guide the direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at employing [an URL scheme](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310023344/https://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/12/22/using-app-url-schemes-in-ios/) for your second application.

Comment: link is not valid

Comment: I put in a web archive link. It'll take time to access, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to start another application from yours, you have to use URL Schemes.
Just register a custom scheme on your other app and call such URL from the first one.
Here there is a tutorial that might help you:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL SCHEME, please see the [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/)