# To get Dialing screen to appear on clicking a button in iPhone app

Tags: ios

I have got a requirement in my app which is that- On clicking a button we have to make dialing screen (calling screen) to appear as next view. Is this possible to do so? Please suggest me the way how can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to open a dialing screen as a new view. You can only leave your program and open default iphone dialog screen as a new process (your application will be in the background in this moment). To do this use this code to dial number:

```
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12342333"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL]];
```

Comment: This won't work. You need to have `tel:` at the start of the URL.

Comment: Actually I want that screen to come on clicking a button which comes when we tap phone button in iPhone. I don't want to call just a single number.

Comment: It's not possible, see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone

Answer (score 0):

For example in your action button block:

```
NSMutableString *phone = [[@"+ 12 34 567 89 01" mutableCopy] autorelease];
[phone replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                       withString:@"" 
                          options:NSLiteralSearch 
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [phone length])];
[phone replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"(" 
                       withString:@"" 
                          options:NSLiteralSearch 
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [phone length])];
[phone replaceOccurrencesOfString:@")" 
                       withString:@"" 
                          options:NSLiteralSearch 
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [phone length])];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: What's the point of all of that string manipulation on a string literal? You don't need to strip any of that out anyway.

Comment: @rmaddy Why? The string can contain "(,), white spaces" and etc.

Comment: Actually I want that screen to come on clicking a button which comes when we tap phone button in iPhone. I don't want to call just a single number. so please tell me is it possible and give solution for the same.

Comment: @LegendReborn What do you mean? Please be more specific.

Comment: @UlasSancak You posted a literal string and then proceeded to replace characters that don't exist in it. Regardless, you don't need to strip those characters. You can create a `tel:` URL with spaces and parentheses. You just need to escape the URL properly like any other URL with certain characters in it.

Comment: I mean: When we tap on phone button provided in iPhone we get a screen in which we can dial a number and call on that number. I just want this functionality to come in my app's button click method.

Comment: @rmaddy I know that but if the tel string coming from a database or etc which you cant sure what is inside of it, you should use strip...

Answer (score 0):

For further reader of this question two app in iOS can interact the [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/) shows a demo how this can be done with the URL scheme in iOS.