# Open Google+ Application in Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, social-networking, xcode4.5, google-plus

I making a social application which requires Google+. I know that I can open Google+ as a link to Safari (Which isn't really user Friendly having to switch apps just to post something). This code opens the link to Safari:

```
    -(IBAction)Google+:(id)sender  {  
            NSLog(@"Google+");
        //The link will go to Stack Overflow Google+ Page
        NSURL *GooglePlus = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://plus.google.com/+StackExchange/posts"];
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:GooglePlus];        
 }
```

But is there a way to detect if Google+ Application is installed and open the application there (And if it isn't then open the link to Safari). I thank Everyone who take the time to read my post (Even if you didn't) :)

Comment: this might help: http://danielamitay.com/blog/2011/2/16/how-to-detect-installed-ios-apps

Comment: @Ponf's response might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone) it is not possible to run an app within another app but it is possible to launch any app that registers a `URL Scheme`. You should check if that's the case for the `Google+ Application`.

**EDIT**
Google+ doesn't seem to be on the [list](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) :-(

Comment: Thats a Bummer their isn't any Google+ Support (Maybe in iOS 7 :)

Comment: The version of iOS doesn't matter. This is something that Google would have to add to the Google+ app. They could do that at any time.

Answer (score 7):

Now you are able to launch Google+ app using next protocol:

```
gplus://
```

For example

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:@"gplus://"]];

**UPD:**
So, to launch any page in G+ app you just need to change https:// in URL on gplus://, for example this will launch user profile:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gplus://plus.google.com/u/0/105819873801211194735/"]];
```

Comment: Hello ponf, can I open google plus app with user name. Like If i dont have 105819873801211194735 like id. then can I open google plus with name

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6 and Swift, you can write:

```
                let gplusURL = "gplus://your url"    
                if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL.URLWithString(gplusURL)){
                   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.URLWithString(gplusURL))
                }
                else{
                        var alertView = UIAlertView()
                        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                        alertView.title = "HEY"
                        alertView.message = "It seems Google Plus is not installed on your device"
                        alertView.delegate = self
                        alertView.show()
```