# how to launch another app in our app on tap of an icon

Tags: cordova

I am developing an ipad app using phonegap.
and want to launch another from my app on the tap of the icon.
Can any one help me how to launch it. And what all do I need for launching another app.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone

Comment: I have found 1 more option Which really has worked for me.          Here is solution :                                                           <a href="#" onclick="app.startMyApp()">Try to start MyApp</a>                 startMyApp: function()
    {
        document.location = 'HelloWorld://'
    }                                                                    Here, HelloWorld is the name of the url scheme of the app which you want to launch.