# Open one App from another programmatically

Tags: ios, url-scheme

We have a standard SAP BI App and we don't have the code for that and our company purchased it for our internal use and now my PM has asked me to open SAP BI App from our custom App programmatically and I have done it using url scheme's and then I am facing the problem he wants me to open  our custom App automatically when ever the user clicks on a specific button in standard SAP BI App for which I don't have any code.

Is it possible to open my custom App from SAP BI App.

Comment: Contact SAP and ask them for the details on that app's URL schema in case that is not documented.

Comment: I am able to open SAP App from my App

Problem is how to open my App from the SAP App again (I don't have the code of SAP App)

Answer (score 7):

The only way to open an app from other app is to enable it in the code of the app you want to be opened. If that app dones't provide a URL scheme to open it, you can't'

Read more here:

[Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

Comment: Yes yes I know that process that buddy but the problem is I don't have the code for that standard SAP APP and when I click on any button on that standard SAP App I need to open my App in which I have provided the URL Scheme

Comment: is there any way to open my App from the standard SAP App when I click on any button in that App

Answer (score 4):

`URL Schemes` are the only way to [communicate between apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18).Apps that support custom `URL schemes` can use those schemes to receive messages.For example, an app that wants to show an address in the Maps app can use a `URL` to launch that app and display the address.
and Here is something useful that i [found related](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need set a custom URL scheme in your second app for that. Check [this tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) or simply do a search with "iphone custom URL schemes". There's a lot of good tutorials.