# How to paste a number to dialer screen from app?

Tags: ios

I want to paste a number to the dialer screen on button click from an app in iPhone.

All I have found till now is the 'tel' URL which automatically dials the number, or the 'telprompt' URL which gives a prompt before dialing a number.

Is there a way to just open the dialer with the number entered, and not an auto dial or prompt?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tel: url schema to open the dialer with the number entered.
tel:+123456789

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know but you could display the telephone number in the UIAlert so the user can see it before choosing to dial or not.