# How to start third-party app from my app in iOS?

Tags: ios, url, url-scheme

I want to use an already installed app (ProCamera) from my app.On click of a button an already downloaded and installed app (ProCamera) should be launched from my app.I have searched and understand that its possible through custom URL scheme.But this app (ProCamera) is downloaded from AppStore,so can I add Custom URL to the downloaded app.

Please help me with possible solution.And also if this is possible or not?
Thanks

Comment: Find out if `ProCamera` provides its own custom URL scheme. If it does, use it to launch the app. If it doesn't, there is no way to launch the app from yours.

Comment: Thanks Maddy for your Quick response,I have searched for the Custom URL of ProCamera from [link](http://handleopenurl.com/),but no success.Is there any other source to find out that.?

Comment: check out this link. maybe it will help you.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone

Comment: Unzip the ProCamera.ipa and look at the Info.plist file. The ipa should be on your computer in `/Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications`.

Comment: BTW - why does your question title talk about downloading the app from the store but your entire question is about launching an already installed app? These are conflicting statements. Please update one or the other to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to launch ProCamera is to ensure it has its own custom URL scheme. If there is none, you, unfortunately, are unable to launch it from your app.

**Update**: try this one `procameraapp://`