# how can i import another application in an application in iOS

Tags: ios

my english is poor,i face with a problem in iOS development:
in app A,i want to import app B,to startup app B by touching one button from app A,not use url scheme(openurl),just like a plug embedded to app A, how can i complete it？i have app B code；or may like from project A import project B,how to startup project B

Answer (score 0):

URL schemes are the only way to do this. See here for more:

[Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

You could also send a local or push notification from App A to App B, but that would require an extra step of user interaction in order to launch App B.

Comment: Then I don't think what you want to do is possible.

Comment: like an phone bank app,from this app to a stock app,now i need to complete it ,if use url scheme,if local do not have stock app, it must come to appstore,so  i try to avoid it

Comment: one last project completed,i do not how to package an static library and add one interface file