# How to read the output from system() command in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, command-line, system, tcpdump

I am using the below code to get tcpdump output of a URL in iOS, but it is printing in console, how can i get the response to NSString object?

```
system("tcpdump -i en1 -A -vvv host www.facebook.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think tcpdump have output file param, or you can use output redirect, and then read all from saved file

```
tcpdump -l -i en0 -A -vvv host www.facebook.com  > /tmp/facebook_packets.txt
```

`tmp` path just for example, use any you like

#### edit:

and alternative way, redirect output to `NSPipe`, see answer here [How to get the log from system();?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21870018/1403732)

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createFileAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/output.txt"] contents:nil attributes:nil];

 NSString *strCmd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tcpdump -i en1 -vvv -A host www.facebook.com > /%@",[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/output.txt"]];
system([strCmd UTF8String]);

Comment: I tried with above code, but the file is not creating at the location, how can i fix this?

Comment: I see you missed `-l` flag

Comment: and you have two slashes in path `//output.txt`

Comment: @PalchuriSudheerKumar please, also check link I added to answer, I guess this also can help you

Comment: I tried below code using NSTask, but getting error when i run the code, please help me to fix this

Comment: NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"tcpdump"];
    [task setArguments: [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"-i",@"en1",@"-A",@"-vvv",@"host",@"www.facebook.com", nil]];
    
    NSPipe *pipe= [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];
    
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
    
    [task launch];

Comment: also, you must put full path to tcpdump

Comment: Error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'

Comment: try `/usr/sbin/tcpdump` or search to get real path to executable

Comment: Crash issue resolved with your suggestion, after the execution of code , getting error in console, please see below, any idea why it is?

Comment: tcpdump: en1: You don't have permission to capture on that device
((cannot open BPF device) /dev/bpf4: Permission denied)