# Pokemon GO iOS URL Scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme, pokemon-go

Does the iOS version of Pokemon GO contain a URL Scheme for purposes of launching Pokemon GO from another iOS application?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24363049/1226963

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL Scheme has changed to `com.googleusercontent.apps.848232511240-dmrj3gba506c9svge2p9gq35p1fg654p` in version 1.1.0. Version 1.1.1 uses this URL Scheme also.

---

Discovered the URL Scheme thanks to [@rmaddy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448571/pokemon-go-ios-url-scheme?noredirect=1#comment64303356_38448571). The URL Scheme to open Pokemon GO on an iOS device is, `b335b2fc-69dc-472c-9e88-e6c97f84091c-3://`. Seems like they do not intend for other developers to use the URL Scheme considering the way it is formatted. **I'd be cautious implementing this in a published application for now**.

Swift example:

```
// Check if Pokemon GO app installed on device
if let url = URL(string: "b335b2fc-69dc-472c-9e88-e6c97f84091c-3://"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
else {
    // Pokemon GO not installed
    // Do something else
}
```

Also, starting at iOS 9 you must include `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your `info.plist`.

[image: info.plist]

Comment: Have you tested on more than one device?

Comment: @Droppy I have only tested on my development device. I'm hesitant to put it in a published application because of the formatting. I'm assuming it will change.

Comment: version 1.3.1 uses: "com.googleusercontent.apps.848232511240-dmrj3gba506c9svge2p9gq35p1fg654p"