# Can I open Aliexpress app from my app iOS?

Tags: ios, url-scheme, aliexpress

Is it ok and is there any scheme I can use to open AliExpress app within my own app? "aliexpress://" not working

The point here is on the way to open it with no complaints from Apple and Ali. This is quite large marketplace with quite big audience. So, I'd like to ask if there any LEGAL way to open their App as we do on registration with FB for instance.

Thanks for links in comments, but it's considered as not a proper way to solve my issue, it worked for a while as I know, but then stopped.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/workflow/comments/2tlx29/get_url_scheme_of_any_app/).

And then it looks something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448571/pokemon-go-ios-url-scheme?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Also here's a very relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24363049/1032372).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open iOS application from Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362381/open-ios-application-from-unity)

Comment: B2B is the only reliable way with usage of url schemas or universal links, whatever