# Launch Third-party IOS app with Unity3D

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I want for my Unity3D Professionnal application launch a Third-Party IOS App on a Ipad but I didn't found a correct way to do it.

I'm not the developper of the IOS App so I don't have the URL Type to launch it with "Application.OpenURL("awesomeapp://")"

Did someone already do something like this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to retrieve the URL scheme of a 3rd party app? here is how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362381/open-ios-application-from-unity/24363049#24363049

Comment: I've tryed but the third app is secured lock so I can't access URL Type in Info.plist

Comment: Oh didn't know that was possible. Would you mind sharing the link to the app, so that I could take a look?

Comment: sure ! it's https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/e-doc-browser/id1003220647?mt=8

Comment: i had no issue opening up the ipa and the Info.plist. try this: `Application.OpenURL("smarteredoc://")`