# Open HealthKit App from another app

Tags: ios8, healthkit

I want to build a fitness app that will upload the data to HealthKit. Is there any way to open/navigate to HealthKit from another app?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On iOS 10, the Health app URL scheme is `x-apple-health`. You can open it from within your own app by calling:

**Objective-C:**

```c
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"x-apple-health://"]];
```

**Swift:**

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "x-apple-health://")!)
```

See [Open Health app using url scheme | Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61442).

Comment: Only work on iOS 10+.  I don't think the Health app on iOS 8 or 9 has a registered URL schema.

Comment: @bickster You're right, it doesn't seem to work on iOS 8 or 9. I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know how to open a special view? Like steps or weight?

Comment: This is not officially documented or supported, and could change at any time. I don't recommend you use this.

Answer (score 4):

iOS does not provide a general API for launching other applications and the Health app would need to have support for URL scheme in order for you to launch it from your own application.  See [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone).

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5 "Safer way"**

```
func openUrl(urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
openUrl(urlString: "x-apple-health://")
```