# Open Health and go to an App's permission via URL Scheme

Tags: ios, healthkit

Can we link directly to Sources then my app? I tried to open an URL like `x-apple-health://sources/MyApp` but it only open Sources and not goes directly to MyApp. Anyone knows if that's even possible?

EDIT: this is not a duplication of [Open HealthKit App from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259488/open-healthkit-app-from-another-app) as I know how to open Health app itself - I would like to know whether it's possible to go directly to an app's permissions, not just the general Sources tab.

Comment: thx @hardikbar but my question is a bit more concrete than that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. Even x-apple-health://sources is undocumented and therefore not supported. You should file a bug with Apple.

Comment: thx @Allan - I've filed a suggestion report at Apple. Will keep this question updated.

Comment: @Roosevelt No progress I guess?

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk yeah no progress... I didn't even get an answer from Apple :/

Comment: no way. i found it. [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"x-apple-health://"]];