# open my iOS application using HTML5 and pass parameters to it

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, html, url

I want to create a link using HTML5 which will launch my iOS application when user open it and pass an argument to my app.

Is it possible to accomplish? and if yes, can anyone help how to achieve it?  and what should I add in my project to handle these argument?
Thanks.

Comment: Use deep linking concept, http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

Let me know if you need example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through tutorial about URLSchemes:

[Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

It requires few parameters settings in info.plist and a method handling in AppDelegate class: 
[application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method

Hope this will give you initial start for study.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, can you please upvote the same.