# open phone app on IOS with AS3 code

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, nativeapplication

Is it possible, with AIR app, to automatically open the phone app on IOS when the user clicks on the number ?

I've managed to do so with Android :

```
phoneNumber.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, phoneClick, false, 0, true);

function phoneClick(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("tel:255050"));
}
```

But it's not working on IOS.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: What you have appears to be correct for iOS.  Supposedly, it "must not contain spaces or brackets (it can contain dashes and "+" signs, though)".  See the two following links for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Phone

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can do it using the Native Extension. You have to develop the Native Extension for your application and AIR Application will pass the request to the Native Extension and Native Extension will be execute it.

Native Extension is nothing but Native Application development which will be provide OS Level request execution from AIR Application.

Please refer given below link to get How Native Application will open another application: [Click Here For Native Application Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)