# Can I interact with my iOS phone app from Watch notification?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I have voip application that runs on iPhone. I know that I can modify notifications on the watch so that it has buttons Answer and Reject call. I have read that button press can run background task on the phone. Does this mean I can answer my voip call that is incoming to my app from the watch? I am aware that I will need the phone to talk, but was wondering if I could answer and reject from the watch, without pulling the phone out of my pocket?

Comment: Are you developing for watchOS1 or watchOS2? If you are using watchOS2 check out WatchConnectivity and send a message to the phone when the notification arises.

Comment: Currently I am interested in watchOS1. Is there a way to start the phone app from the watch?

Comment: I don't think you can start an app from code. Never seen this behaviour before.

Comment: Check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone

Comment: Philip thanks for the link. But this case is different. If you want to make app that runs on the watch you have to add code to your iPhone app. I do not want to run another app. I want to run my own. So I was wondering if I could start the app that is kind of already running in the background in some way...