# How to open App in iOS using "appname://openApp?"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to open another app with parameters from my iOS App.

I have specific URL scheme provided from the developers of the App that have to be opened:

```
secondApp://openApp?param1=XXX&param2=YYY
```

I try to search Google how to open App in this way but I did not found any example how to use this construct.

Can you provide me with link or a row of code how to open App in this way?

Comment: check Inter-App Communication tutorial https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look into this documentation of [Inter-App Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW2) provided by Apple. Also, you can look into this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629). Here, they are sending text to another app. Also, another detailed answer to your question can be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone).

Following code from the tutorial will help you :

```
-(IBAction) openReceiverApp {
// Opens the Receiver app if installed, otherwise displays an error
UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *ourPath = @"secondApp://openApp?param1=XXX";
NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
if ([ourApplication canOpenURL:ourURL]) {
    [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is potentially quite a good answer, it is essentially a "link only" answer. You should include some information from your links so that if the information behind the links is ever changed/lost, the answer still makes sense. See [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Thanks for informing, I will edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

To open second app from your iOS app, just use:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"secondApp://openApp?param1=XXX&param2=YYY"];  //fill your params
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```