# Open wechat app account (chat conversation) in iOS app

Tags: html, ios, wechat

Does anyone knows if I can have an deep link in my iOS app to wechat account? I have an developer account with wechat (Chinese acc) just want to check if there are ways to deep link wechat account in my iOS app. So is there a way to deep link in my iOS app to wechat account chat?

Comment: what do you mean by deep linking? What  feature of we chat you want to use from your mobile app?

Comment: @Bluewings is there a way to transfer user to wechat app on ios app? when user click on a button on my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the url schemes to open another iOS Apps from your iOS app.

Find below code to open the wechat app from your app when pressing button.

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
  NSString *customURL = @"weixin://";

  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
  }
  else
  {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"URL error"
                              message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No custom URL defined for %@", customURL]
                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
  }

}
```

refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18)

Another [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone).