# redirecting users from within an app to another app

Tags: ios, banner

We have a feed app. Our client has requested us to check the option of adding a banner to the feed, which will appear constantly and will redirect the user to a 2nd application in the Apple Store. 
If the user has the 2nd app installed on the device, the 2nd app will open. Of the user does not have the 2nd app installed on the device, he/she will be diverted to the app's page in Apple Store.
There is no monetization involved here. Is this a valid functionality of a banner within an iOS app? I couldn't find any comment regarding this kind of functionality in the Apple Store Review Guidelines. Many thanks!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone . if you find url then open that app otherwise open your appstore app url using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 1):

The thing u are looking for is URL Schemes. You can open another app from currently opened app only when u have a registered url scheme for that app.
 If that app doesn't provide a URL scheme to open it, you can't.

Check this [Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629)

And, it is not possible to launch arbitrary application, but the native applications which registered the URL Schemes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I now understand that what we are requested to do is technically doable. The question now is whether it is allowed to have this banner constantly redirecting the user to the same app. Any idea?

Comment: OfCourse u can. Why don't u use a UIView instead of banner?

Comment: My concern is that a constant banner which is redirecting the users to the SAME app at all time, is a reason for Apple to reject our app. I haven't found any comment regarding this in Apple review guidelines, but I am concerned this is a reason for rejection. What do you think?And - What is the difference between using a banner and using a UIView? And what are the pros and cons for going with each option?