# Open iOS app through PowerPoint

Tags: ios, hyperlink, powerpoint

We made a unity iOS app for our client, now he would like to open his app through a PowerPoint presentation which is on his iPad. It isn't a problem with Keynote, we can simply add a hyperlink like this one ***yourappName://*** and it works, but in PowerPoint it opens the browser instead of the app.

Is it possible to launch an app through PowerPoint?

Comment: You will need to add your app's name in URL scheme (in .plist) of Powerpoint, which you obviously can't. So I think it is not possible. Also you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone

Comment: You would add your app's custom URL scheme in your app's Info.plist file. Not in Powerpoint's Info.plist file. But another problem is that Powerpoint does not let you add a link with a custom URL scheme to a document. When you try to add a link to 'yourappName://'  it changes it to a file:// link.  So I think it only lets you add "real" HTTP(s) web links.

Comment: yeah that is what I figured out as well ... hmm

Answer (score 0):

Actually now that Apple introduced **Universal Links** in iOS9 this might now be possible. With this feature you can now define that a link to https://yourwebside.com will open your iOS app (if it is installed).

The process to enable this is a bit complicated and needs some adjustments on a web server. Check out this [tutorial](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9) that describes what needs to be done.

I don't know if this effort is justified in your case but technically it should be possible.