# Deep link to Medical ID tab of Health app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, deep-linking, healthkit

The [Medical ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203037#medical) is a vital and potentially lifesaving feature of iOS 8+, but it is underutilized. I'm building a custom healthcare app with Swift 2 which contains a list of emergency preparation steps that users can check-off once they've done them. In an effort to increase awareness of the Medical ID feature and communicate its importance to our users (and first-responders) I'm making it an item in that list.

I know that it's possible to [launch another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone) from our apps, so I could just launch the Health app. However, since we can also deep link into certain specific areas of an apps if the destination app supports deep linking, it would be easier to link straight to the Medical ID tab. That would remove the need to explain to users that they need to tap the Medical ID tab after Health app opens. It's a small thing, but lowering any complexity or confusion that could be a barrier to setting up the Medical ID could save some lives.

I didn't see anything about deep link support in the HealthKit API documentation, but I may have missed it.

**Question**: Has Apple's made it possible to deep link directly to the Medical ID tab of their [Health app](http://www.apple.com/ios/health/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no support for deep linking into Health.app.