# plist not allow add URL types key

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

> Allows me to add URL types and everything I need, but when I close the plist and open it again, URL types are gone.

I need to add this, so I can open the app from an iMessages extension.

I'm following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone#24033837)

When my second app is ==> `parent` and firstApp is my `iMessageExt`.

**But I do not understand why this happens to me with the url types, I do not know if there is any kind of restriction that when I delete them delete them immediately**

***EDIT:***

My .plist

[image]

Comment: can you show your plist data here so we can get idea what you set in your plist ?

Comment: @CodeChanger added