# Launch an app from within another without scheme(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to launch another iPhone application or appstore from within another app?, For example in my application if I want the user to open another of my application from current app. (close/minimize the current app, open the Phone app). We searched and found its possible with SharedApplication. But it requires to update all our apps. We posted without customUrl or schemes. We are using Objective-C.

Comment: i think sharedApplication will minimise your current app and open the another app. not close the current app.

Comment: its ok for me too. but i need another method other than sharedApplication.

Comment: Custom URL Schemes is the only one solution.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone