# How do I redirect instagram users to my Xcode app after login

Tags: swift, xcode, uri, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

How can I get a valid URI that redirects users to my app after logging in with Instagram?

I have it completely set it up to where users can log in.

Now all I need is for it to redirect the user back to the app I created in Xcode.

I don't want to use a web page because I believe that's tedious when I try to log in it says URI is not matching.

Comment: I have never worked with the instagram-api, but if there is a way to inject code in it, here is how you do it for two app which you control: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Custom URL Schemes.

You will basically set a custom URL Scheme for your app, and then make that the redirect URI in Instagram, when the user logs in using Instagram and then redirects to that URI, your app will be opened again.

Here is an [old xCode 5 example](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/XCode/CustomURLs.htm) of how it works.

For more information you can check out the [Apple documentation on Inter-App Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html).

Your question is a bit vague so I hope this helps but it is hard to answer with better code examples if we don't really know what it is you need help with.