# Create a button to open another app in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a simple app in Flutter  that contains for example 3 button , the event `onPressed` in the button should open another external app , is that possible in Flutter and how should I proceed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Column`/`Row` to create your buttons. And after that you can simply use a `RaisedButton` like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // use android_intent package to open other app
    final intent = AndroidIntent(package: "com.android.facebook", action: "action_view");
    intent.launch();
  },
  child: Text("Open Facebook")
)
```

It's easy to do it in Android using [`android_intent_plus`](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus) and for iOS you can do it natively, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone) will help you.

Comment: thank you so much for your help 
does "your_ui_here" has to be like "com.android.facebook" for example,?
and what about IOS ?

Comment: Yes, it should be the package name. And for iOS there is no way of launching it. Sorry!

Comment: is it possibile if we work with react native or Ionic ?
or i have to develop on swift separatly ?

Comment: I am not sure if RN, or Ionic would be able to that, and you may do it natively, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

Comment: although i installed android intent package it always ndicates an error about the Launch et canLaunch as undefined a

Comment: I actually combined `url_launcher` code with that, please checkout the updated solution.

Comment: E/flutter (32361): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:android_intent/android_intent.dart': Failed assertion: line 35 pos 16: 'action != null': is not true.

Comment: that's what was displayed in the debug console

Comment: You should pass an `action`, I updated the code, unfortunately I am not on Facebook so not able to test it on my own, please give it a try and let me know.

Comment: i ve tried the package in the link below 
https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps#-readme-tab-

Comment: it worked but it is mentioned that it only for android for the moment

Answer (score 0):

In my case action: "action_view" caused app selection dialog getting opened. We can open specific component using below.

You can try [android_intent library](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) for launching external app. Documentation has some sample codes.
You may use sample code below.

```
var map={"AuthParams":authParam};
var intent=AndroidIntent(package:"in.app",arguments: map,componentName: "in.app.ui.splash.SplashActivity",/*action: "action_view"*/);
await intent.launch();
```