# Can we move from native code to react native code in a published Apple app?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I was planning to rewrite an existing IOS app using react native. The existing IOS app is already published in the APP store.

1. I would like to know if it is possible to completely create a new build and release the new react native app to the app store ? My guess was to just change the bundle identifier of react native app to the one on the existing App to get released. But not sure if it is the right way.
2. Also if we publish, can we test it before it is released to users or will it immediately reflect ?
3. The alternate idea would be to create a new app and redirect them to the new app. This is even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can create a new build and publish on AppStore with the same identifier
2. Before publish you can test your build on a simulator or real device. If you have a bigger group that wants to test you can use AppCenter with Ad-hoc certificates
3. If it is the same app but only the technology changed it would be better to just replace that app instead of redirect

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it's possible, you should use the same Bundle Identifier and Signing Certificate.
2. Yes, you can test it by yourself or upload it to TestFlight and send to beta testers.
3. You can implement redirect button in the "old" app that will open "new app", but it's not user-friendly). More details on how to implement this -  [Launch an app from within another (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)