# How to get any App's Bundle ID or App ID in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

Is there a way to know any App's bundle ID or App ID which is running in the foreground? I have seen this feature in this App called Backbone, which asks user to open any App, press a button on their hardware (Which is a game controller, connected to iPhone via lightning connector) and then a link/shortcut to that App gets added in their App. It seems like they are able to establish a link between their App and other Apps, based on what I know so far it is not possible without knowing the Custom URL scheme of the App.

Anyone knows if there is another way it can be done?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is no app called Backbone. Give us link of this app...

Comment: Here you go -

https://apps.apple.com/sg/app/backbone-next-level-play/id1449660663

Answer (score 1):

URL Schemes are the only way to communicate between apps. So, no, it's not possible to launch any other apps.

But it is possible to launch any app that registers a URL Scheme, whether it's Apple's, yours, or another developer's.

[For more info, check this question discussions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)